# iOS __kindof NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been checking out iOS 9 new features as a developer and some of them like the StackView look awesome.

When I went the the header file of UIStackView I saw this:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,copy) NSArray<__kindof UIView *> *arrangedSubviews;
```

What is the __kindof on NSArray*. Are we able to specify a type on a NSArray * now?

Little test:

```
@interface DXTEST ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray <__kindof NSString *>  *strings;
@end

@implementation DXTEST

- ( instancetype ) init {
    self = [super init];

    if( self ) {
        _strings = [NSMutableArray new];

        [_strings addObject:@(1)]; <-- compiler warning wieeeeee
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: You are attempting to add the wrong type?

Comment: That is the beauty! Before this would just work but now with __kindof it shows me i am adding the wrong type. But I cannot find any documentation so I don't know whats up

Comment: Nope; that's the use of generics, not `__kindof`.

Comment: In Xcode 7,  Objective-C supports Generics which allow you to specify type information for collection classes like NSArray, NSSet, and NSDictionary.  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html

Comment: @trojanfoe I got it! I like this addition a lot in my current codebase

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Sadly the currently top voted answers are a bit incorrect.

You actually *can* add any subclass of `<T>` to a generic collection:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView @end
@implementation CustomView @end

NSMutableArray<UIView *> *views;
UIView *view = [UIView new];
CustomView *customView = [CustomView new];
[views addObject:view];
[views addObject:customView];//compiles and runs!
```

But when you'll try to retrieve the object, it will be strictly typed as `<T>` and will require casting:

```
//Warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 
//`CustomView *` with an expression of type `UIView * _Nullable`
CustomView *retrivedView = views.firstObject;
```

But if you'll add `__kindof` keyword the returned type will be changed to `kindof T` and no casting will be required:

```
NSMutableArray<__kindof UIView *> *views;
<...>
CustomView *retrivedView = views.firstObject;
```

**TLDR**: Generics in Objective-C *can* accept subclasses of `<T>`, `__kindof` keyword specifies that return value can also be subclass of `<T>`.

Comment: Yes, this is it, it avoids casting.

Comment: *"Sadly the currently top voted answers are a bit incorrect"* Hey, this is now the top voted answer.

Comment: Well then now the top voted answer is a bit incorrect, stating that itself is incorrect :)

Answer (score 41):

> Are we able to specify a type on a NSArray * now?

Yes, through Objective-C's new lightweight generics. In the example you provided, you have a property of type `NSArray`, <strike>which will accept elements that are `UIView`s.</strike>

Now, this can be specified as follows (without `__kindof`).

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,copy) NSArray<UIView *> *arrangedSubviews;
```

And in this case, the array will accept objects whose class is `UIView`, but not any objects which are subclasses of `UIView`. The `__kindof` declaration marks the array's generic type as one which can accept both instances of the `UIView` class, and instances of any of `UIView`'s subclasses.

Edit:

I've removed the bulk of my original answer since I mistakenly thought specifying the type of the array would prevent you from inserting objects of an incorrect type, and this is not the case. (Thanks to [Artem Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1568491/artem-abramov) for pointing this out. Please [see his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33013094/716216) below for additional details)

Objective-C's generics seem to exist to give you type information when accessing the elements of a generic collection. For example, consider the following code which adds a `UIView` and a `UIImageView` to `NSMutableArray<UIView *>`. Both objects are inserted into the array without any complaints by the compilers or the runtime, but when you try to access the elements, you're warned by the compiler if the type of your variable is anything other than the generic type of the array (`UIView`), even if it's one of `UIView`'s subclasses.

```
NSMutableArray<UIView *> *subviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[subviews addObject:[[UIView alloc] init]]; // Works
[subviews addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] init]]; // Also works

UIView *sameView = subviews[0]; // Works
UIImageView *sameImageView = subviews[1]; // Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIImageView *' with an expression of type 'UIView *'

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([sameView class])); // UIView
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([sameImageView class])); // UIImageView
```

Now, this produces a compile time warning, but does not crash at runtime. The key difference between this and the same example where the array's generic type is marked as `__kindof`, is that the compiler won't complain if you try to access ones of its elements, and store the result in a variable who's type is `UIView` **or** one of its subclasses.

```
NSMutableArray<__kindof UIView *> *subviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[subviews addObject:[[UIView alloc] init]]; // Works
[subviews addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] init]]; // Also works

UIView *sameView = subviews[0]; // No problem
UIImageView *sameImageView = subviews[1]; // No complaints now!

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([sameView class])); // UIView
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([sameImageView class])); // UIImageView
```

Comment: Oh damn, this is very nice. Is this mentioned somewhere in the WWDC videos?

Comment: @ScareCrow I believe it is in a few of the videos, but it is discussed in the most detail in the [Swift and Objective-C Interoperability](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=401) talk ([link to transcript](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/401?q=objective-c%20generics)).

Comment: That's not correct, you can add subclass of `UIView` to `NSArray<UIView *>`. See my answer below.

Comment: @ArtemAbramov Thanks for pointing that out! I've made the necessary corrections to my answer.

Comment: lightweight generics are discussed in this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-401
__kindof is discussed at this point in the video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-401/?time=1752

Comment: `UIImageView *sameImageView = subviews[1]; // No complaints now!
`... why is this a good thing?? It could be a `UIView`. Then you'd get a crash if you tried to access `UIImageView` specific properties...

Answer (score 7):

iOS9 introduced lightweight generics on ObjC. ObjC is a really dynamic language while SWIFT prefer static types, to maximize interoperability and type checking now in ObjC you can declare an array like that:

```
NSArray<UIView *> *views;
```

That means that all the views object are instances of UIView objects, imagine the `UIView` subviews property it can contains elements that can be of different types, `UIView`s and objects that inherits from `UIView`, but the compiler will complain because even if they inherits they are different types.
That is were `__kindof` come into play. Is like to say that the array contains objects that are kind of type `UIView`.
Is like still using the advantage of an `id` type but restricted to a kind of class.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the use of `__kindof` to allow subclasses.  It's a shame Apple introduce a feature that works slightly differently to generics in every other language in this day and age.

Answer (score 3):

@Artem Abramov is correct. I want to point out additional point, as mentioned in [Objective-C Generics](http://www.russbishop.net/objective-c-generics)

> `__kindof` says this thing must be X or a more-derived class. Why is this necessary? The docs don't call this out but I suspect its because
>   adding generics to Objective-C introduces a massive conundrum: If
>   `UIView.subviews` is now `NSArray<UIView *>` then a whole lot of code is
>   now invalid according to the compiler's type checker:
>   `[view.subviews[0] setImage:nil]` is bogus because UIView doesn't have
>   an image property. We've been spoiled by the fact that the Objective-C
>   compiler will let you send any visible message selector to id... only
>   now the subviews array doesn't return id, it returns `UIView *`. Oops.
>
> `__kindof` solves that problem by saying the subviews array isn't explicitly an array of UIView * but an array of `UIView *` subclasses.
>   **Then the compiler will let you send any selectors that could apply to
>   `UIView *` or all its subclasses, or assign an element from that array
>   to a `UIImageView *`**, but it will still complain if you attempt to do
>   this: `NSNumber *n = view.subviews[0]`.

And this is a feature of Clang introduced in Xcode 7. I don't think it is anything related to iOS version

Answer (score 2):

If you have a function that returns `__kindof SomeType *`, then you're able to assign result of that function to a variable of type `SubtypeOfSomeType *` without the explicit cast. Without `__kindof` compiler will complain about incompatible types.

Actually there's at least one function like that in UIKit: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Now let's extend that knowledge to `NSArray`. Specifying `__kindof` in generic type parameter adds that `__kindof` to return type of `-objectAtIndex:` and `-objectAtIndexedSubscript:` (well, actually to any method of generic NSArray that returns `ObjectType`), and now you can easily assign result of calling `stackView.arrangedSubviews[i]` to any variable that has a type that is a subclass of `UIView` or `UIView` itself.

Important note: you can store `UIView` subclasses in `NSArray<UIView *>` just fine, even without `__kindof`. `__kindof` is only about *accessing* elements of array.